# Convert html "href=" into "link_to" for Rails 4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

This is the code i want to convert into link_to

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://www.example.com/gigs?category=Video+and+animation">Show me everything</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://www.example.com/gigs?subcategory=Intro">Intro</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://www.example.com/gigs?subcategory=Animation+%26+3D">Animation & 3D</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://www.example.com/gigs?subcategory=Editing+and+Post+Production">Editing and Post Production</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://www.example.com/gigs?subcategory=Other">Other</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this is how it looks like

[image: droptdown]

How would you convert for example

> `<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"
>   href="http://www.example.com/gigs?subcategory=Intro">Intro</a></li>`

**Into** `<%= link_to "Intro", some_path(that goes to the above Url), method: :get %>`

Or how would you add this **method: :get**,to the html **href** above,i need it for endless scrolling,turbo links is causing problems,so i have to use **method: :get**

This is the seeds.rb i sued to create the category with its subcategories

```
@category = Category.create!(name:  "Video and animation")

["Intro", "Animation & 3D", "Editing and Post Production", "Other"].each do |name|

@subcategory = Subcategory.create!(name: name, category_id: @category.id)

end
```

Comment: i have to keep everything as it is,but add this element 'method: :get',i think i can apply it only if i convert the html above into ruby link_to,i might be wrong of course.See i use there href="" so i have to convert it to link_to,otherwise use somehow the "method: :get" directly into this html href.

Comment: You can also use it in HTML <a> tag as `<a href=XXX method="get">`  but by default if you are not mentioning any method, its taken as get

Comment: no need to give (method: :get ) in link_to

Comment: @AnantKolvankar i have to for my endless scrolling,sometimes it doesn't work because of turbo links,and method :get solves my problem.

Comment: ok you can try using this <%= link_to "Intro", some_path(that goes to the above Url), method: :get , "role"= >"presentation", "tabindex"=>"-1" %>

Comment: you can add `data-method="get"` in your anchor tag. That will solve your problem

Comment: you can disable turbolinks for these links by adding 'data-no-turbolink' => true to your links

Comment: @user123 This worked please post your answer

Comment: @AdnanDevops yours would work as well,but user123 answer worked in my case,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://www.example.com/gigs?category=Video+and+animation" data-method="get">Show me everything</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://www.example.com/gigs?subcategory=Intro" data-method="get">Intro</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://www.example.com/gigs?subcategory=Animation+%26+3D" data-method="get">Animation & 3D</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://www.example.com/gigs?subcategory=Editing+and+Post+Production" data-method="get">Editing and Post Production</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://www.example.com/gigs?subcategory=Other" data-method="get">Other</a></li>
</ul>
```